# how does DAG affect the NONCE finding？what about fix the DAG size to 1G？

Tags: nonce, dag

I'm going to decrease DAG size on private net, by change the algorithm.go code
 `var datasetSizes = [maxEpoch]uint64{
    1073739904, 1082130304, 1090514816, 1098906752, 1107293056,
    1115684224, 1124070016, 1132461952, 1140849536, 1149232768,
    1157627776, 1166013824, 1174404736, 1182786944, 1191180416,
    1199568512, 1207958912, 1216345216, 1224732032, 1233124736,
    1241513344, 1249902464, 1258290304, 1266673792, 1275067264,
    1283453312, 1291844992, 1300234112, 1308619904, 1317010048,
    1325397376, 1333787776, 1342176128, 1350561664, 1358954368,
    1367339392, 1375731584, 1384118144, 1392507008, 1400897408,
    1409284736, 1417673344, 1426062464, 1434451072, 1442839168,
    1451229056, 1459615616, 1468006016, 1476394112, 1484782976,
    1493171584, 1501559168, 1509948032, 1518337664, 1526726528,
    1535114624, 1543503488, 1551892096, 1560278656, 1568669056,
    1577056384, 1585446272, 1593831296, 1602219392, 1610610304,
    1619000192, 1627386752, 1635773824, 1644164224, 1652555648,
    1660943488, 1669332608, 1677721216, 1686109312, 1694497664,
    1702886272, 1711274624, 1719661184, 1728047744, 1736434816,
    1744829056, 1753218944, 1761606272, 1769995904, 1778382464,
    1786772864, 1795157888, 1803550592, 1811937664, 1820327552,
    1828711552, 1837102976, 1845488768, 1853879936, 1862269312,
    1870656896, 1879048064, 1887431552, 1895825024, 1904212096,
    1912601216, 1920988544, 1929379456, 1937765504, 1946156672,
    1954543232, 1962932096, 1971321728, 1979707264, 1988093056,
    1996487552, 2004874624, 2013262208, 2021653888, 2030039936,
    2038430848, 2046819968, 2055208576, 2063596672, 2071981952,
    2080373632, 2088762752, 2097149056, 2105539712, 2113928576,
    2122315136, 2130700672, 2139092608, 2147483264, 2155872128,
    2164257664, 2172642176, 2181035392, 2189426048, 2197814912,
    2206203008, 2214587264, 2222979712, 2231367808, 2239758208,
    2248145024, 2256527744, 2264922752, 2273312128, 2281701248,
    2290086272, 2298476672, 2306867072, 2315251072, 2323639168,
    2332032128, 2340420224, 2348808064, 2357196416, 2365580416,
    2373966976, 2382363008, 2390748544, 2399139968, 2407530368,
.....}`

to this:`var datasetSizes = [1]uint64{1073739904}`

and then change the code in algorithm.go

`func datasetSize(block uint64) uint64 {
    return datasetSizes[0]
}`

and the same as cachesize like that.

so my question is after changing the cache and DAG size, what will happen on the NONCE finding process ini mining?
although i know the function about nonce finding code

```
func hashimoto(hash []byte, nonce uint64, size uint64, lookup func(index uint32) []uint32) ([]byte, []byte) {
// Calculate the number of theoretical rows (we use one buffer nonetheless)
rows := uint32(size / mixBytes)

// Combine header+nonce into a 64 byte seed
seed := make([]byte, 40)
copy(seed, hash)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(seed[32:], nonce)

seed = crypto.Keccak512(seed)
seedHead := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(seed)

// Start the mix with replicated seed
mix := make([]uint32, mixBytes/4)
for i := 0; i < len(mix); i++ {
    mix[i] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(seed[i%16*4:])
}
// Mix in random dataset nodes
temp := make([]uint32, len(mix))

for i := 0; i < loopAccesses; i++ {
    parent := fnv(uint32(i)^seedHead, mix[i%len(mix)]) % rows
    for j := uint32(0); j < mixBytes/hashBytes; j++ {
        copy(temp[j*hashWords:], lookup(2*parent+j))
    }
    fnvHash(mix, temp)
}
// Compress mix
for i := 0; i < len(mix); i += 4 {
    mix[i/4] = fnv(fnv(fnv(mix[i], mix[i+1]), mix[i+2]), mix[i+3])
}
mix = mix[:len(mix)/4]

digest := make([]byte, common.HashLength)
for i, val := range mix {
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(digest[i*4:], val)
}
return digest, crypto.Keccak256(append(seed, digest...))
```

}

and the DAG is used in lookup function.

so, anyone know the relationship about nonce and DAG in the funtion hashimoto? and what about fix the DAG into 1G?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the nonce size is independent of the DAG size. In ethereum the nonce has a fixed size but DAG increments.

One of the reasons to increment the DAG size is to make harder for hardware with a fixed amount of memory to be used with ethereum, ie ASIC.

Comment: thanks, Ismael. I found the reason why ethereum uses DAG: https://www.vijaypradeep.com/blog/2017-04-28-ethereums-memory-hardness-explained/. this page tells the so-called "memory-hard" way to mine. Ethereum use DAG to restrain the lookup function to restrict nonce finding.